# What non third world country would allow me to work temporarily?

Tags: visas, work, dutch-citizens

I am planning on going on a 10 month trip after my study as a Dutch citizen. In this 10 months I mostly want to travel, but as money will be needed at some point, I also want to work. 
By that time I will be 24 years old and have a master's degree, but as big companies probably won't hire me for 2-3 months I am aiming at more simple jobs like being a waiter, a postman, or something along those lines.

From [this](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13901/what-do-i-need-to-work-and-travel-in-the-us-for-10-months-as-a-dutch-citizen) question I understand that my plan will not be executable in the USA as I'm not allowed to work on a nonimmigrant visa.

What non third world countries do allow temporary employment of foreigners in a way that will make my plan feasible?

Comment: How old are you?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Mostly if you're 18-30 you can get working holiday visa for [Australia](http://wikitravel.org/en/Australia#Working_holidaymaker_scheme), [New Zealand](http://wikitravel.org/en/New_Zealand#Short_term) and [Canada](http://wikitravel.org/en/Canada#Work) (the ones I know of). Citizens of many countries can get these visas but Dutch for sure.

As mentioned in the comments, as a EU passport holder, you also have the right to work anywhere in the EU, in Switzerland and in EEA countries (Norway, Iceland, Liechtenstein) with the possible exception of new EU members (Romania and Bulgaria until 2014 and Croatia after that) if your own country imposes restrictions to citizens from said new members.

Comment: I think Korea and Japan also have these working holiday visas. You can also simply add that a Dutch citizen is allowed to work in the Schengen area.

Comment: Schengen area, that's right. But countries offer work and travel visa have a good supply of easy, short term jobs such as fruit picking and so on. The kind he was looking for.

Comment: The OP would be entitled to work in Switzerland but none of this is related to Schengen, it's a basic principle of the EU. A Dutch citizen can thus also work in the UK or Ireland. In Switzerland, it's a result of the earlier EU-Swiss bilateral agreement. Swiss citizens also enjoy the same rights across the EU.

Comment: btw. Norway's labor market is unrestricted for all EU members.

Comment: @Annoyed: right, done.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I'm aware, the only country outside of the EU/EEA which allows for unrestricted work by citizens of other countries is Georgia. As outlined in a [related question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4413/is-it-really-permitted-for-travellers-to-work-while-visiting-georgia-on-a-touris) there aren't any restrictions on working there, at least for citizens of countries which don't require a visa to enter Georgia.

On a more practical note - assuming you're interested in non-skilled work, the best option is to spend some time in Switzerland (since it has the highest minimum wage in Europe), earn some cash, and then spend it on traveling abroad at your own leisure. This is a lot more productive than slaving off in remote countries where the pay is 2-10 times lower for the same kinds of jobs.